# What's the best way to capture a signature online?

Tags: php, flash, html, canvas, tablet

I'm building a website application in PHP that requires a signature from the end user.

For this part of the website it will be exclusively viewed on Windows based tablets.

So, my question is this:

What's the best way to capture a signature online?

I've looked at flash or HTML5 canvas/excanvas, but I am seeking a more experienced answer.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by signature? I mean like an email/forum signature? or a ssh fingerprint?

Comment: Given the use of 'tablets', I would assume a written signature.

Answer (score 12):

From: http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature

> jSignature is a JavaScript widget (a jQuery plugin) that simplifies
>   creation of a signature capture field in a browser window, allowing a
>   user to draw a signature using mouse, pen, or finger.
>
> Works in all mainstream browsers that support Canvas or Flash Captures
>   signatures as smooth vector images. (Yes, SVG is supported!)
>   Ingenious, super-efficient (i.e. not lagging) real-time curve
>   smoothing. Allows manipulation of signature strokes, like “Undo last
>   stroke” Automatically adapts to your page’s layout and colors. Free
>   and Open Source.

The documentation is very clear and the demo shows you how it works.

Answer (score 5):

I needed to capture signatures for a current project and found Signature Pad to be very useful.  It uses HTML5 canvas, json and jQuery.

https://thomasjbradley.github.io/signature-pad/examples/accept-signature.html

Comment: The above link is dead, please replace with correct one, https://thomasjbradley.github.io/signature-pad/examples/accept-signature.html

Answer (score 1):

Flash would be great if you need to support older tablets, running non HTML 5 capable systems. Some things to keep in mind:

Try to transfer the data as a common image format. GIF or PNG would be ideal. This will make it far easier to keep track of and to parse through at a later date. Future-proofing, since a custom or uncommon format may fall out of favor faster.

Transfer the data over a secure connection. Always.

Remember that the legality of this is dubious. Both for use as a binding contract, and also for the transfer of the signature itself. Consult a lawyer if you haven't yet. Ideally one who deals with digital contracts.